# Wordpress doesen't process AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm having trouble processing an AJAX request on my Wordpress site. A plugin that I'm writing needs to serve a shortcode with a script that should dispatch an AJAX request back to the plugin, which should send back some JSON data.

Shortcode `[payment_form]` being served:

```
public function initPaymentFormShort()
    {
        ob_start();

        wp_register_script('Stripe', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', null, null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('Stripe');

        wp_enqueue_script('payment.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/payment.js');
        wp_localize_script( 'payment.js', 'ajax_post_params', array( 'ajax_post_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

        include __DIR__ . '/../templates/payment_form_short.php';

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Request handler registered to process the request:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_public_key', array($this, 'handleGetPublicKey'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_public_key', array($this, 'handleGetPublicKey'));
```

Handlers are registered within the `plugins_loaded` action

Part of the `payment.js` script that dispatches the request:

```
function getPublicKey() {
  return fetch(ajax_post_params.ajax_post_url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({action : 'get_public_key'})
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      stripeElements(response.publicKey);
    });
}
```

The request gets sent to: `http://mysite.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` (served with Flywheel Local if that matters)

The response is a 400 Bad Request with a 0 in the body. **The handler doesn't get executed at all**.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress's ajax API does not use JSON encoded requests. You need to do form-encoded. Something like this should work:

```
function getPublicKey() {
  return fetch(ajax_post_params.ajax_post_url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: 'action=get_public_key',
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      stripeElements(response.publicKey);
    });
}
```

Note that the body is `urlencoded`. So if you had multiple parameters it would look something like this:

```
action=get_public_key&foo=bar&baz=bin
```

All modern browsers also support the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API so you can also generate these query strings like this:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams({
    action: 'get_public_key',
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'bin'
});
let body = params.toString();
```

That would be the preferred way of generating form data query strings for complex data sets.

Comment: @MarkoKrizan Glad it helped, if this solved your issue, please mark it as the answer to close the question.